# Translate Objective-C code to recognize links to Java for Android

Tags: android, objective-c

I'm developing an android application and I want to recognise links that are inside a EditText. I have the next code that works in objective-c and I want to do it in java. I guess that will be do with a vector (string links[]), but I don't know.

```
NSError *qwerror = nil;
NSRegularExpression *qwregex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(http://\\w+.\\w+.\\w+.\\w+.\\w+.)" options:0 error:&qwerror];
NSArray *qwmatches = [qwregex matchesInString:textView.text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, textView.text.length)];
NSMutableArray *qwwords = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *qwmatch in qwmatches) {
    NSRange qwwordrange = [qwmatch rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString *qwword = [textView.text substringWithRange:qwwordrange];
    [qwwords addObject:qwword];
}
NSString *allLinks = [qwwords componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but I read this as a "do my work for me" question. Please try to do as much work as you can and ask about specific details where you get stuck, don't set the entire task in front of us and ask for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

String input = /* text from edit text */;

String[] words = input.split("\\s");
List<URL> urls;

for (String s : words)
{
    try 
    {
        urls.add(new URL(s));
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        // not a url
    }
}

// urls contains all urls from 'input'.
```

Comment: Why the down vote? This is the correct way to parse a URL In java, is it not?