# How extract the data from a list?

Tags: java, android, tweets

I'm developing an Android application and I want to recognize hashtags, mentions and links. I have a code that can be usable in objective-c that do my propose. I question [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566449/translate-objective-c-code-to-recognize-links-to-java-for-android/10566572#10566572/) and now I have these code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

String input = /* text from edit text */;

String[] words = input.split("\\s");
List<URL> urls=null;

for (String s : words){
try 
{
    urls.add(new URL(s));
}
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // not a url
}

}
```

Now I want to put these on a tweet, I have developed the code to do it, and the tweet is based on an string. **My question is how I put the data from the list in the string?**

```
//I test these
String tweet="Using my app"+urls
```

But in the tweet appears "Using my appnull"

**How I reuse this code to recognize hashtags and mentions?**

```
I think that is changing the input.split("\\s") by "@\\s" or "#\\s"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a library here:
https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-java
that does what you're trying to do.

Comment: Much better than reinventing the wheel.